# Typescript name of key in Object

Tags: javascript, typescript

Suppose we have object like this:

```
foo = {
   "currency": "dollar"
}
```

Is it possible to check if value of object exists and is equal to dollar?
For example:

```
const bar = currency;
```

So how can we pass the value of bar to foo path? Or use any syntax that should work as $bar? I don't want to pass $bar as a path name but a value of bar as a path.

```
foo.$bar? true: false
in result  foo.currency === true or false
```

Or even is it possible to have another object like:

```
anotherobject.anotherpath.$(getKey(foo))
```

to get object like anotherobject.anotherpath.currency? 
Hope it's clear enough to understand

Comment: Are you maybe looking for `foo[bar]`? Like in `foo[bar] == "dollar"`?

Comment: @Aioros,
mate I don't want to check the value, but if the specific path exists.
This way I want to be sure if path foo.$bar exists, where $bar = currency.

Comment: you can do `if (bar in foo && foo[bar] === 'dollar')` where `bar = 'currency'` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation

Answer (score 1):

Objects act a bit like arrays in that you can access values stored in a certain index using the bracket notation - but in this case, using the key or field in place of the numeric index.

So you can:

```
const foo = { "currency": "dollar" };
const bar = "currency"

if (foo[bar] == "dollar") { /* do something */ }
```

If you want to check if the 'bar' property exists in the foo object, you can also do:

```
const foo = { "currency": "dollar" };
const bar = "currency"

// will check if foo.bar exists
if (foo.hasOwnProperty(bar)) {/* do something */}
```

Comment: As I've mentioned, I don't want to check if value of 'currency' is 'dollar' but I want to check if foo.$bar exists, where $bar = currency :)

Comment: the hasOwnProperty function will check if the foo object has the 'currency' field, is that what you needed?

Answer (score 1):

```
var foo = {
   "currency": "dollar"
};
var bar = "currency";
```

Check if the key exists:

```
if (foo[bar])
```

Or:

```
if (foo.hasOwnProperty(bar))
```

Check if property has the right value

```
if (foo[bar] == "dollar")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

example is below:

```
var foo = {
   "currency": "dollar"
};
var bar = "currency";


console.log(Object.values(foo).indexOf(bar) >= 0); //false
console.log(Object.keys(foo).indexOf(bar) >= 0); //true
```